# will_paginates not showing records when clicking the pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate gem, for pagination of an array of records.

It is showing the pagination links. Let us say first 5 records by default, but when I click on page 2, the whole page goes blank.

code is below:-

```
 <%@report=@report.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5) %>
 <%= will_paginate @report %>
```

here @report is array of records.
Please help

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete. What is the link generated by will_paginate for page 2?

Comment: it is:-
http://localhost:3333/leaves/report?page=2

Comment: see my answer below. `.paginate` call should be in the controller, not in the view. You are recursively reassigning @report in the view.

Comment: no, >@report is not equals to Report.all, its an array of records based on some conditions.
and wanted to use >@report.paginate, its working fine in my other controller.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, in your view, you have done a

```
@report = Report.all
```

You should change that to

```
@report=Report.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

This is the first line in your code snippet above. `.paginate` will fetch from the database a number of records equal to `per_page` (the `LIMIT`), every time you navigate from one page to another.

It will use `page` as an `OFFSET`. So if you are accessing page 2, the value of `OFFSET` is

```
 (page number - 1) x per page 
 (2 - 1) x 5 = 5
```

Meaning, page 2 will display records with id from 6 `(OFFSET + 1)` till 10 `(OFFSET + LIMIT)`

for 5th page, offset will be

```
  (5 - 1) x 5 = 20
```

So records on page 5 will have id from 21 to 25. and so on...

To enable will_paginate do this, you should call `.paginate` on the model `Report`. not on the instance variable `@report`